# Replace certain values in data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, na, outliers

I have a `data` as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 Wt=c(91,92,85,205,285,43,95,75,76,NA),
                 Ht=c(185,182,173,171,600,650,NA,890,NA,NA))
```

`Wt` represents the weight in kilograms and `Ht` represents the height in centimeters. In this example, I want to treat the values of `Wt` bigger than 200 as outliers and change to some specific numbers.
Also, I want to treat the values of `Ht` bigger than 250 as outliers and change to `NA`.
In my actual `data`, there are few outliers in `Wt` and many outliers in `Ht`.
So, I could find the outliers for `Wt` by using the code below:

```
a1<-data$Wt 

a1<-data.frame(a1)
a1<-na.omit(a1)
b1<-a1[a1$a1>200, ]
b1  #205,285
```

I want to change 205 to 80 and change 285 to 90. (Because, in my actual data, there are few outliers for `Wt`, so that I can change them individually.)
Also, I want to make the values of `Ht` bigger than 250 as `NA`. So my expected output is as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 Wt=c(91,92,85,80,90,43,95,75,76,NA),
                 Ht=c(185,182,173,171,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it *by reference* using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[Ht > 250, Ht := NA]
data[Wt == 205, Wt := 80]
data[Wt == 285, Wt := 90]
data
    id Wt  Ht
 1:  1 91 185
 2:  2 92 182
 3:  3 85 173
 4:  4 80 171
 5:  5 90  NA
 6:  6 43  NA
 7:  7 95  NA
 8:  8 75  NA
 9:  9 76  NA
10: 10 NA  NA
```

For more info, see: [Introduction to `data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

---

To implement the `ifelse` method suggested by Shawn in `data.table`, you could do something like the following. This is still updating by reference, so there is still no need to write something like `data <- data %>% ...`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, `:=`(Ht = fifelse(Ht > 250, NA_real_, Ht),
            Wt = fcase(Wt == 205, 80, 
                       Wt == 285, 90,
                       rep(TRUE, .N), Wt))]
```

Note that `fifelse` is `data.table`'s *fast* `ifelse`, and I use `fcase` to handle the two `Wt` conditions together (although the [`rep(TRUE, .N)` trick](https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable/issues/110) is a bit hacky, so maybe it would be nicer to just use two `fifelse` calls for `Wt` instead of `fcase`).

---

Update 2023-07-17: If you need a vectorised option, I suggest using `plyr::mapvalues`. Even though `plyr` is retired, you can just use `body(plyr::mapvalues)` and do the same thing for it's few dependencies, and hence put the code into your own project.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is useful. I also wanted to add an alternative answer in case you may find it helpful to learn other functions. You can plug in any values you want with `ifelse` and the functionality of the `tidyverse`. As an example, I use `mutate` here to create variables and `ifelse` to simply transform the values you wanted. Below is essentially just your data and two functions combined into one command:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(Wt = ifelse(Wt > 200,
                     "9999",
                     Wt),
         Ht = ifelse(Ht > 250,
                     "NA",
                     Ht))
```

Annotated below is what I am doing with the code:

```
library(tidyverse) # load this library for %>% and mutate

data %>% # use this data 
  mutate(Wt = ifelse(Wt > 200, # take Wt over 200
                     "9999", # replace with this value
                     Wt), # otherwise use the original Wt value
         Ht = ifelse(Ht > 250, # take Ht over 250
                     "NA", # replace with this value
                     Ht)) # otherwise use the original Ht value
```

Which should give you any desired output depending on how you use it:

```
   id   Wt   Ht
1   1   91  185
2   2   92  182
3   3   85  173
4   4 9999  171
5   5 9999   NA
6   6   43   NA
7   7   95 <NA>
8   8   75   NA
9   9   76 <NA>
10 10 <NA> <NA>
```

Try it out and lemme know what you think!