# How to rename a specific value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have column name "tourney_name" and one of the values of the column has the incorrect name. It is named Us Open instead of US Open. How do I change this? Below shows the unique names of the Grand Slams in tennis on the data set. I don't want to rename the column name, but how to revalue this? Also, this is my first question, so I'm sorry if I made some mistake.

```
Atp_together_68_21 %>%
  filter(round == "F", tourney_level == "G") %>%
  select(tourney_name) %>%
  unique() 

        tourney_name
1       Roland Garros
2           Wimbledon
3             US Open
4     Australian Open
210           Us Open
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13871614/10366237 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73589347/10366237.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `purrr:modify_if()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% mutate(tournay_name = modify_if(tournay_name, ~.x == "Us Open", "US Open"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. Very quick response

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer an alternative, in `data.table` you could do it *by reference:*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[tourney_name == "Us Open", tourney_name := "US Open"]
```

Note that running this line of code will not print any output - by default the output is not printed and it is as if you typed `df <- df %>% ...`. If you run `df` in console you will see that `df` was changed.

Comment: very simple transformation, +1. I wonder if we can use similar code to modify elements "in place" within dplyr

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr` from `tidyverse` to replace any instances of the mis-capitalized word.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(tourney_name = str_replace_all(tourney_name, fixed("Us Open"), "US Open"))
```

Or in base R:

```
df$tourney_name <- gsub(fixed("Us Open"), "US Open", df$tourney_name)
```

**Output**

```
       tourney_name
1     Roland Garros
2         Wimbledon
3           US Open
4   Australian Open
210         US Open
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(tourney_name = c("Roland Garros", "Wimbledon", 
"US Open", "Australian Open", "Us Open")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "210"))
```